# writing unit test cases for an interface which has methods without arguments

Tags: java, junit, interface

I have an interface which has a method without arguments

```
public interface HealthStatus {
    Integer healthCheck();
}�
```

The implementation is as below

```
 @Override
    public Integer healthCheck() {
        Integer status = 0;
        try {
            SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
            if (proxyConfigProperties.getEnabled()) {
                Proxy proxy = new Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyConfigProperties.getUrl(), proxyConfigProperties.getPort()));
                simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
            }
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(simpleClientHttpRequestFactory));
            ResponseEntity<String> healthResponse = restTemplate.exchange(eVerifyGovernmentProperties.getUrl(), HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
            status = (healthResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) ? 200 : 202;
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }

        return status;
    }�
```

How can I unit test this method for positive scenarios and negative scenarios.

Edit:

I have refactored my class as below

```
@Service
@Qualifier("implementation")
public class HealthStatusImpl implements HealthStatus {

    @Autowired
    RestTemplateConfig restTemplateConfig;

    @Autowired
    private EVerifyGovernmentProperties eVerifyGovernmentProperties;

    @Override
    public Integer healthCheck() {
        Integer status = 0;
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> healthResponse = restTemplateConfig.getRestTemplate().exchange(eVerifyGovernmentProperties.getUrl(), HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
            status = (healthResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) ? 200 : 202;
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }

        return status;
    }

}
```

Here is the class which instantiates the RestTemplate

```
@Component
public class RestTemplateConfig {

    @Autowired
    ProxyConfigProperties proxyConfigProperties;

    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate(){
        SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory simpleClientHttpRequestFactory = new SimpleClientHttpRequestFactory();
        if (proxyConfigProperties.getEnabled()) {
            Proxy proxy = new Proxy(java.net.Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress(proxyConfigProperties.getUrl(), proxyConfigProperties.getPort()));
            simpleClientHttpRequestFactory.setProxy(proxy);
        }
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(simpleClientHttpRequestFactory));
        return restTemplate;
    }
}
```

Comment: you can implement the interface and use this class on test (instead of current implementation), question is what you want to test exactly

Comment: You can't. Spring is about dependency injection, and dependency injection is about making code testable by allowing to inject fake (mock) dependencies in tests. Your code shouldn't create its own RestTemplate. Instead, it should use an injected RestTemplate, so that you can use a RestTemplate bound to a fake server in your tests.

Comment: @JBNizet I have refactored the class as per your suggestion. How can i proceed from here.

Comment: See https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/web/client/MockRestServiceServer.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is what you want to mock :

```
restTemplateConfig.getRestTemplate().exchange(eVerifyGovernmentProperties.getUrl(), HttpMethod.GET, null, String.class);
```

but this will require deep mocking and that is also a bad smell : you should not need to define such a statement to invoke the rest template. This responsibility should be defined in a specific class.
So move it into a method of a specific bean for example `RestTemplateService` that will relieve you from passing as many as parameters and it will also balance better responsibility of this class by reducing its dependencies  :

```
ResponseEntity<String> healthResponse =  restTemplateService.getForHealthCheck();
```

Now just mock it with Mockito.
Concerning `RestTemplateService`, you could create your own class or rely on Feign (here [Spring Feign](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi_spring-cloud-feign.html) makes more sense)  that enables declarative rest client via interface.

It would give :

```
public class HealthStatusImpl implements HealthStatus {

    private RestTemplateService restTemplateService;

    // favor constructor injection
    public HealthStatusImpl(RestTemplateService restTemplateService){
        this.restTemplateService = restTemplateService;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer healthCheck() {
        Integer status = 0;
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> healthResponse = restTemplateService.getForHealthCheck();
            status = healthResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful() ? 200 : 400;
        } catch (Throwable th) {
            th.printStackTrace();
        }

        return status;
    }
}
```

Note that  `Status.is2xxSuccessful()` is generally better as it returns true for any successful response (`200`, `201`, etc..).  And if it is not successful you want to return an error response code.

From the unit test side, you should mock this dependency and record a mock behavior according to your scenarios.
Note that in your case, you don't want to load a whole spring context but you want to perform a plain unit test, that is without container. So don't use `@SpringBootTest` but only JUnit and Mockito.

For example with JUnit 5 :

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class HealthStatusImplTest{

    private HealthStatusImpl healthStatusImpl;

    @Mock
    private RestTemplateService restTemplateServiceMock;

    @BeforeEach
    public void beforeEach(){
        healthStatusImpl = new HealthStatusImpl(restTemplateService);
    }

    @Test
    public void healthCheck_when_200_is_returned(){
       Mockito.when(restTemplateServiceMock)
              .getForHealthCheck().thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK));
       assertEquals(200, healthStatusImpl.healthCheck());
    }

    @Test
    public void healthCheck_when_200_is_not_returned(){
       Mockito.when(restTemplateServiceMock)
              .getForHealthCheck().thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND));
       assertEquals(400, healthStatusImpl.healthCheck());
    }

}
```

Of course the `RestTemplateService` should also be unitary test and unitary tests don't relieve from writing integration tests for higher level components.

Comment: Hi David, When I mocked the RestTemplateService, It is failing. Could you please help.Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'ProxyConfigProperties' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

Comment: Hello wandermonk, you didn't write an unit test but an integration test as you load a spring boot context. if you stick to what I proposed, it should be fine.

Comment: But i am getting nullpointer exception if i write as it is at 

 Mockito.when(restTemplateService.getRestTemplateForUrl())
                .thenReturn(new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.OK));

Comment: Because restTemplateService is not mocked. if you use JUnit5 follow my way. Otherwise if you use JUnit4 annotate your class  with `MockitoJUnitRunner.class`: such as `@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class YourTest {
    //...
}`

Comment: Also i am getting nullPointerException for healthStatusImpl.healthCheck()

Comment: While debugging i made this assertEquals(200, 200); and it worked. But it is giving nullpointer if i change that to healthStatusImpl.healthCheck(). This has been frustrating me for hours.

Answer (score 0):

To unit test a web client such as a RestTemplate based class, you need a framework which mocks the server, e.g.

- the one from Spring: MockRestServiceServer:

  - https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-rest-client
  - https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mock-rest-template
- WireMock: http://wiremock.org/docs/getting-started/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that your check `(healthResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK)` is correct, because if a status is not `2xx` `RestTemplate` throws `HttpStatusCodeException`.

That's why it's always better to have some mocks if you integrate with a third party side.

That's why I also recommend you to consider `MockRestServiceServer` in your tests. see @Puce answer for links.

Also, there is no necessity to create a new `RestTemplate` for each request.

That's why I also recommend you to consider constructor injection. see @davidxxx answer for refactoring approaches. And don't forget to put connection timeouts in your `RestTemplate` settings.